# Katalon is not opening

Tags: katalon-studio

**Hi,**
While opening the Katalon Studio, I am receiving the below mentioned error and attached the log file for reference.

Please look into this and suggest to proceed further.

**Popup Error while opening Katalon:**
An error has occurred. See the log file.
D:\Katalon Studio_Windows_64-6.1.2\config\metadata.log

> !SESSION 2019-07-16 11:12:08.921
>   ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.version=1.8.0_181 java.vendor=Oracle
>   Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32,
>   NL=en_US Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64
>   -data config
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2019-07-16 11:12:29.317
>   !MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous
>   session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-16 11:12:29.473 !MESSAGE An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources (195). !STACK 0
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   com.kms.katalon.util.ApplicationSession.clean(ApplicationSession.java:36)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.preRunInit(Application.java:88)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519) Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element
>   '/C%%Users%vdavuluri2%Katalon Studio%Govt Inquiry%Govt
>   Inquiry.prj/bin/groovy/AssignInquiry004.class' not found.     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:596)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:51)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:832)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:519)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:742)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
>     ... 52 more Root exception:
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element
>   '/C%%Users%vdavuluri2%Katalon Studio%Govt Inquiry%Govt
>   Inquiry.prj/bin/groovy/AssignInquiry004.class' not found.     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.AbstractDataTree.handleNotFound(AbstractDataTree.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.getData(DeltaDataTree.java:596)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:51)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.NoDataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(NoDataDeltaNode.java:60)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DataDeltaNode.asBackwardDelta(DataDeltaNode.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.asBackwardDelta(DeltaDataTree.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:832)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:831)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.DeltaDataTree.reroot(DeltaDataTree.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.watson.ElementTree.immutable(ElementTree.java:519)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.restore(SaveManager.java:742)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.startup(SaveManager.java:1587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2399)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)  at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:758)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   com.kms.katalon.util.ApplicationSession.clean(ApplicationSession.java:36)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.preRunInit(Application.java:88)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-16 11:12:29.488 !MESSAGE An error
>   occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core
>   (257). !STACK 0 org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting
>   module.   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:590)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
>   com.kms.katalon.util.ApplicationSession.clean(ApplicationSession.java:36)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.preRunInit(Application.java:88)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.application.Application.start(Application.java:56)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: I'd ask that their support channels

Comment: https://forum.katalon.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete all the files in the config folder